# Catch specific server on nginx

Tags: http, nginx, https, proxy, http-proxy

My nginx file looks like:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name local.awesome.com;

    ssl_certificate /opt/certs/local.awesome.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /opt/certs/local.awesome.com.key;

    location / {
        root /var/www/awesome.com/public_html/;
        index index.html;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.local.awesome.com;

    ssl_certificate /opt/certs/local.awesome.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /opt/certs/local.awesome.com.key;

    root /var/www/api.awesome.com/public_html/;

    # Known locations for static resources
    location /resources/ {
    }

    # Process all other requests via JS in index.html
    location / {
        rewrite .* /index.html;
        break;
    }

    location /api {
        rewrite "^/api/(.*)$" /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://api:8001;
    }
}
```

If I query something similar to:

```
GET https://api.local.awesome.com/api/
```

This works fine.

I decided to make this accessible globally to share some data.

I'm trying to request:

```
GET https://192.168.1.3:443/api/
```

But this doesn't work. It returns `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`.

This request returns `403 Forbidden`:

```
GET https://192.168.1.3:443/
```

It looks like everything is with authorization here, but I hope that previous request should return something different from `Not Found`.

What is wrong here and how to replace:

```
GET https://api.local.awesome.com/api/
```

with

```
GET http://192.168.1.3:443/api/
```

If schema or port are different it's not critical for me.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

```
curl -v http://192.168.1.3/api/
*   Trying 192.168.1.3...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.1.3 (192.168.1.3) port 80 (#0)
> GET /api/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.1.3
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.13.3
< Date: Fri, 01 Sep 2017 18:55:05 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 185
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://192.168.1.3/api/
< 
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.13.3</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.1.3 left intact
```

Comment: You want both to work at same time or just one?

Comment: It will be enough to have just one working alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change below

```
listen 443 ssl;
server_name api.local.awesome.com;
```

to

```
listen 443 ssl;
listen 80;
server_name api.local.awesome.com _;
```

or

```
listen 443 ssl;
listen 80;
server_name api.local.awesome.com 192.168.1.3;
```

This would allow you to access it using `http://192.168.1.3/api/`

Comment: It returns `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`. I've changed into your second suggestion.

Comment: Is this the complete config you posted, or you have something more also ? also what is the output of `curl -v http://192.168.1.3/api/`

Comment: I've updated the question with the response of curl. This is all configs from a config file, but it looks like 80 port may be used by nginx container: `docker ps | grep nginx
2258ae964073        nginx:alpine        "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   8 hours ago         Up 8 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp`

Comment: You have some more config which is doing the http to https redirect inside the container. The config you have posted is not the only one for nginx.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I've found an additional config file with this redirect: `# Permanently redirect all HTTP requests via HTTPS to the same URI.
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
`